# Python: Rename files error

Tags: python, batch-rename

I have a spimple script to rename all files in directory (ex. 475435_name.psd) by increasing its number lets say by 10.

But I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mstopienski/Desktop/Desktop/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.rename(filename, newname)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '810858_Hero_ProjectHP_1600x487.psd' -> '810868_Hero_ProjectHP_1600x487.psd'
```

I dont want it to move files I just want the names changed.

```
import glob, os
path = input()
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    number = filename[0:6]
    name = filename[6:]
    x = int(number)+10
    newname = (str(x) + name)
    os.rename(filename, newname)
```

Comment: It tries to find the file in the current directory. This is probably not the same as where the file is located. So either provide full path or change current directory.

Comment: That being the case, probably changing the last line to: os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, newname)) would do it?

Comment: The problem is that there is no second file.
'810868_Hero_ProjectHP_1600x487.psd' is created of the first one
It looks like he is lookin for this second file to overwrite?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from @RvrK, the script is trying to target the working directory for the rename so I'm guessing chaning the last line to:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, newname))
```

Should do it?

Edit:

Adding some 'safety' features:

```
import glob, os
path = input()
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    basename = os.path.basename(filename)
    number = basename [0:6]
    name = basename [6:]
    x = int(number)+10
    newname = (str(x) + name)
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, newname))
```

Comment: No, it did not help.
I've got 6 files in directory but none of them is named as second from error. It  is created from 1st one.

Comment: Dont know, how to tell?

Comment: Is the error message you get exactly the same as it was before? Copy and paste it here)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mstopienski/Desktop/Desktop/naming.py", line 7, in <module>
    x = int(number)+10
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'c:\\Use'

Comment: OK, so the error you're getting is quite different now... I'll update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need over look the path you input and see if a file ends with '.psd',
try this snippet code will help:

```
import os
path = raw_input()
for filename in os.walk(path):
  for ele in filename:
    if type(ele) == type([]) and len(ele)!=0:
      for every_file in ele:
        if every_file.endswith('psd'):

           number = every_file[0:6]
           name = every_file[6:]
           x = int(number)+10
           newname = (str(x) + name)
           os.rename(os.path.join(path, every_file), os.path.join(path, newname))
```

I tied put the script and your psd files in the same path input "./" it works.

Comment: Thanks but it is not always a psd file.

Comment: how to change to every extension file?

Comment: I don't know that if your files are all like six-numbers and something else,if they are, just try: int(every_file[0:6]). If they are not, you should find a way by your own.Good luck.